# Error while decomposing a time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, trend, decomposition

I'm coding to forecast using ARIMA model. The data is one single column in .csv file and it is an annual data. Therefore, the frequency = 1.

When I'm trying to decompose my data it gives me an error:

```
time series has not or less than 2 periods
```

I am new to R and want to know if my data has any trend. If it does, than I would like to remove the trend and use the data without the trend in it.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
dataEmployee = read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE, sep=";") 
attach(dataEmployee)
EmployeeTimeSeries = ts(Turnover, frequency = 1, start = 2009, end = 2015)
plot(EmployeeTimeSeries)
Employee.decom = decompose(EmployeeTimeSeries)
```

Comment: If you are just looking for a trend, you could simply regress `Turnover` on a linearly increasing time counter variable using `lm()`, and if you want to, take the `residuals` from that model.

Answer (score 1):

The function [`decompose`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/decompose.html) in R does the following:

> Decompose a time series into seasonal, trend and irregular components
>   using moving averages. Deals with additive or multiplicative seasonal
>   component.

Since you have no seasonality (`frequency = 1`), the decomposition fails. You should look for methods that can work with nonseasonal data instead. The [test-for-trend](/questions/tagged/test-for-trend) tag could be useful.

Comment: Thanks! Is it still possible to do forecasting with arima model when I'm working with a nonseasonal data? And can I go on with forecasting without knowing or removing the trend in the data? Can arima do forecasting with only 7 observations? Or do you need more time horizon when using arima models?

Comment: 7 observations is very few. ARIMA might not work reliably with such a small sample. Something very simple like the overall average, weighted overall average (with newer observations receiving slightly more weight) or the last value may be reasonable. If the trend is real and you expect it there, you could try forecasting by just extrapolating the trend. But anything beyond linear trend may be too flexible with just 7 observations.

Comment: Richard Hardy: For this forecasting I need to add some explanatory variable. I wanted to use the regression with ARMA errors. But that isn't a good idea for only 7 observastions I guess? I am really having trouble putting the external data and internal data in one model which does a good prediction. The external data has more historical periods, can I still combines all the variables? Or do I need to make a prediction of each of the explanatory variables and than do some simple forecasting? How do I take the time in it?

Comment: With so little data I would be really careful so as not to overfit. You will likely have run out of degrees of freedom by the time you throw in the external variables together with the trend. But this is going beyond your original question. If I have answered that one, consider accepting it.