# ARMA errors and combining explanatory variables

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression, forecasting, arma

Currently I'm working on forecasting the employee turnover of an organisation. To do this, I'm using a time series data of the employee turnover over the past 7 years, it is an annual data. To make a good prediction it is also important to add some explanatory variable.

I want to use multiple regression with ARMA errors. But I'm not sure how to use these error to do some prediction.

- Do I need to make a prediction of each of the explanatory variable first, then add this predicted value in the model to do the prediction of the employee turnover?
- Or will the model do all the predictions of the dependent and independent variable and give me a predicted value of the dependent variable (turnover)?

I am really having a hard time putting all the variables in a model that gives me a good prediction. Also, the internal data has only a few observation, whereas the external data has more historical data.

- How can I combine these two data to do a multiple regression?

Answer (score 2):

As [Richard Hardy writes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210876/error-while-decomposing-a-time-series-in-r#comment400596_210881), if you have only seven observations, this is *very* little data. If you first fit an explanatory variable, there is essentially nothing left to fit an ARIMA process to errors to. (Plus, with only seven data points, you don't have enough data to do proper holdout testing!)

I'd recommend simply regressing your time series on one (!) predictor and working with that.

Alternatively, you could try to get higher-frequency data, e.g., monthly or quarterly. Then you could actually expect some seasonal effects and should indeed try to model them.

Comment: But the problem is that I need to use the explanatory variables as well. These variables have more than 7 observations. Can I still combine those?

Comment: If your turnover observations go back only 7 years, then having the explanatory variables go back 30 years won't be helpful, because only the last 7 data points tell you how they influence the turnover. (Perhaps a one-year lag might be helpful, but probably not a two-year lag.)

Comment: So, if I use a multiple regression with ARMA errors, on a data set with 7 observations with both internal and external variable, will it be statistically correct to do a forecasting with a one-year lag?

Comment: How many observations will be sufficient to use all the variables in a model?

Comment: Re your first question: the problem is that with only seven data points, you can't even do out-of-sample testing to validate your model. You might get the best forecasts by taking the overall average, or the last value, or a weighted average with recent data getting a higher weight. Or you might improve on this by using an explanatory variable, whether lagged or unlagged. (If unlagged, you need to forecast this variable, too.)

Comment: Re your second question: a rule of thumb is that you should have twenty observations per parameter. So with one explanatory variable and the intercept, you already need forty observations. Two explanatory variables: sixty observations. This is why I suggested trying to go to higher frequencies.